# Is it allowed to used modifiers in mandatory functions of any token standards that I wish to implement?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

As for example, Is it okay to add modifiers in transfer function in ERC20

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing against that, as modifiers aren't part of the interface you expose. Depending on your modifiers though, it's pretty easy to make any number of integrations impossible (e.g. if you have a whitelist'ed address modifier, the token probably wont be tradeable on exchanges)

Comment: By "whitelist'ed address modifier" do you mean explicit privileges for addresses using a modifier ?